# How to do 3-table Natural Join?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this the correct way of writing three natural joins? :

```
SELECT C.name, P.name 
FROM client C NATURAL JOIN order O NATURAL JOIN product P 
WHERE O.date > '15.02.2011'
```

Comment: What type of database are you using?  (SQL Server, MySQL, etc)

Comment: @dana, There's no `natural join` in SQL Server.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**This is indeed the typical syntax for natural joins.** However, not all databases support natural joins (for instance, I don't believe SQLServer supports it) and I don't believe there is an ANSI standard for natural join.

Note that **natural joins** are generally considered dangerous and something to be avoided - this is because they obscure the join relationship that a query depends on, and could result in queries whose meaning changes if the data model is altered.

Comment: NATURAL JOINs are sadly ANSI, but I agree that they should be avoided.

Comment: +1: Agreed, (imho) logic should explicit and not implicit.  As such, use INNER JOIN instead.

Comment: `NAUTRAL JOIN` is valid SQL-92 syntax. In a truly relational DBMS `NATURAL JOIN` is the only join you need. Any tool is dangerous in the wrong hands.

Comment: @onedaywhen The last statement of your comment should be read in Morgan Freeman's voice.

Comment: @onedaywhen, That depends on how you name your columns.

Comment: @LBushkin, there are use cases for natural joins. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/natural-join/ *"The casual-looking "`Books NATURAL JOIN Checkouts`" is only possible when database naming conventions are formal and enforced."*

Answer (score 2):

To check syntax when your SQL product of choice does not support it, use the [Mimer SQL-92 validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/index.tml). You should discover that `order` and `date` are reserved words. Change them to `my_order` and `my_date` respectively and you will then discover yours is valid Transitional SQL-92 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

using this syntax is considered dangerous as it was already mentioned. Consider the following example:
T1(id, name, age)
T2(id, age, city)

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.name, T1.age, T2.age
FROM T1 NATURAL JOIN T2
```

Which column should be used for join? id or age? It is not defined. Every vendor can implement his own way to solving such problems.

Instead of this syntax, consider using traditional join syntax:

```
SELECT T1.....
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 on T1.id=T2.id
```

Comment: Have you addressed the question? Proper implementation of `NATURAL JOIN` by a vendor should promote better schema design. Yours is a straw man argument. Your `INNER JOIN` syntax is SQL-92 (as is `NATURAL JOIN`). I would consider the "traditional" equivalent join syntax to be `FROM T1, T2 WHERE T1.id = T2.id`.

Comment: Although NATURAL JOIN is standard in SQL-92, Some vendors of leading DBMS's don't support it. Using your "traditional" syntax isn't as common as mine. I should write "common", instead of "traditional" to describe what I meant.